# Android SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I have a problem with a `SearchView`.

There is a shift of the writing top and this is a screen for this SearchView:

[image]

and this is my code:

```
<SearchView
android:id="@+id/search"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/recherche"
android:ems="9"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:textColorHint="#2b3990" />
```

Comment: try removing android:layout_gravity="center_vertical".

Comment: @Sonu Raj: none switching

Comment: put height to wrap_content

Comment: @slama007 Let me know if my answer was fine to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

    android:ems="9"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:textColorHint="#2b3990" />
```

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" correct my problème thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace yours, by this:

```
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/recherche"
        android:ems="9"
        android:textColorHint="#2b3990"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >
    </SearchView>
```